# Are there ASP.NET Session design patterns?

Tags: asp.net, session

Are there ways of structuring session storage in ASP?  I usually put a string as the key, but I'm thinking of taking more stringent measures.

The issue has come up because I have an application that has to use session heavily for 2 reasons:

1. The application has to perform operations on data before presenting it to the user.
2. The application has to validate some choices before writing changes.

My strategy has been to build lists and store them in session on page load.

I'm running into several problems with this.  I keep getting reports of things being 'entered for users,' namely that one of the lists I build and store in session shows values entered before they've had a chance to add them.  I'm not sure why this keeps happening, given that I rebuild the lists stored in session on each load.  I suspect there is a lot of back button pushing.

Are there ways to design the session storage so that the lists stored are unique to that instance of the page?  Or, failing that, a way of designing session storage so that it is always unique to that page?

Comment: " I keep getting reports of things being 'entered for users' and other things." - care to expand?

Comment: Edited the question for more detail.

Comment: Is the data only used within one page request -- meaning it is not necessary to keep it around after the page has finished loading? From your comment below, it seems like you just need to keep the set of lookup values around while binding your listview.

Comment: if you're rebuilding the list on each load....why do you even need to store it in session??

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you use session for data that can be shared between pages, and is specific to a user.

What you're describing is not a good use of session.  Consider what happens if the user happens to open two pages in separate tags - the session data from the 2nd tab will overwrite that from the first, and you're on your way to data corruption.

There is nothing wrong with manipulating data before presenting it to the user, and this is usually performed in your business layer.  If the manipulation is computationally expensive, then consider some sort of caching strategy.

And as @mikek3332002 says, use the build-in validation tools.  Again, there is rarely a reason to use the session as part of the validation.

Comment: I really do not like ASP validators.  They are much more trouble than they're worth, quite honestly.  I could write a javascript validator faster than fixing all of the stuff that comes with those validators.

Comment: I see the point about session...I don't exactly use it for validation.  Here's an example: we have a join table and a look up table.  I need my listview to bind to the reference table, but only for those reference values in the join table.  So on page load, I lookup the join table, build a list of the relevant reference values and store it in session.  Then I bind to my listview.

Answer (score 0):

There is functionality called [viewstate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) which save post-back data per page, on the client's page.

---

### After Editing

Based off the comments it sounds like you more want something that either returns rows where the key is shared amongst 2 tables (SQL's `inner join`) or have the values of one control depend on the property of another control.

The second one is used like (adapted from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163862.aspx)

```
public DataSet GetData(int ID) { ... }


<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsDataSource" runat="server" TypeName="DataDepend" SelectMethod="GetData">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="ID" Type="int" 
        ControlID="ddlList1"
        PropertyName="SelectedValue"></asp:ControlParameter>
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Comment: Your answer would be better if you focused on the ViewState (which is a reasonable option, depending on more clarification about his problem), and got rid of the stuff about validators (which he did not ask about and is not relevant to his problem).

Comment: He did use the word 'validation', you are correct. Admittedly, point 2 is pretty vague, but if you read the whole question, you can see that it has nothing to do with validating client input as the validators do.